# finding next month, previous month giving wrong result

Tags: php

I want to find 2 months after current month and previous month. I have coded as below,

```
$current = strtotime(date('m',time()) . '-01 00:00:01');
$next_month = date('m', strtotime('+1 month', $current));
$next_next_month = date('m', strtotime('+2 month', $current));
$previous_month = date('m', strtotime('-0 month', $current));

echo $previous_month.$next_month.$next_next_month;

output : 01 02 03
```

I want to get the result from current month. And the expected output is `04 05 06`.

How to achieve this result. Is there any solution. Thankyou.

Comment: It may be because you're not using a year in `$current`, have you tried `$current = strtotime(date('Y-m') . '-01 00:00:01');`? Without a year, it might be an invalid date. What is the value of `$current`? Also, I think for `$previous_month` you should use `-1 month` instead of `-0`.

Comment: @rickdenhaan : thanks man. that works.

Answer (score 1):

```
$m = date('m');
printf("%02d %02d %02d", ($m+10) % 12 + 1, $m, $m % 12 + 1);
```

Output (on 2nd April):

> 03 04 05